# How can I merge two JSON strings in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have two JSON strings like these:

```
 $json1 = '[ {"src":"1","order":"2"}, {"src":"10","order":"20"}, ... ]';
```

and

```
$json2 = '[ {"src":"4","order":"5"}, {"src":"6","order":"7"}, ... ]';
```

I am trying to use this to merge them:

```
$images =  array_merge(json_decode($json1 ),json_decode($json2));

$json = '[';
    $comma = null;
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        $comma = ',';
        $json .=      $comma.'{"src":"'.$image['src'].'","order":"'.$image['order'].'"}';
    }
    $json .= ']';
    echo $json;
```

but I am getting this error:

> ERROR: can not use object type of stdCLASS..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you're calling json_decode, you're decoding it as an object. If you want it to be an array, you have to do

```
$images =  array_merge(json_decode($json1, true), json_decode($json2, true));
```

For more information about json_decode:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: If you need merge 2 json_decode objects (and save Key's) = use simple php `sum`, like this `$api_response = json_decode($json1, true) + json_decode($json2, true)`

Answer (score 0):

When you make

```
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $comma = ',';
    $json .=      $comma.'{"src":"'.$image['src'].'","order":"'.$image['order'].'"}';
}
```

You need change for:

```
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $json .=      $comma.'{"src":"'.$image->src.'","order":"'.$image->order.'"}';
    $comma = ',';
}
```

To access the fields of a object you need to use the "->" operator, like $image->src.
Also, the first $comma needs to be null, for this reason I change the order of lines inside the foreach.

Comment: NEVER manually craft a json string.  ALWAYS call `json_encode()` AFTER your array is fully populated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are manually doing what [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) should be doing. This part:

```
$images = array_merge(json_decode($json1), json_decode($json2));
```

is fine.

The individual `json_decode`s inside the `array_merge` will decode into arrays of objects, and `array_merge` will merge them together. You don't need to decode them into multidimensional arrays for this to work.

To get it back into JSON, you should not be using the `foreach` loop and manually constructing the JSON. The error you are getting *is* because you are accessing an object using array syntax, but you can avoid the whole problem by just replacing your `foreach` loop with this:

```
$json = json_encode($images);
```

In fact, the whole thing could be done in one line:

```
$json = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($json1), json_decode($json2)));
```

Answer (score -1):

if you absolutely want to use it as an array, just set it as one .
These can be very useful to set object properties in loops, especially in classes. No your case however.

```
$json1 = '[ {"src":"1","order":"2"}, {"src":"10","order":"20"}]';
$json2 = '[ {"src":"4","order":"5"}, {"src":"6","order":"7"}]';
$images =  array_merge(json_decode($json1),json_decode($json2));    
$json = '[';
    $comma = null;
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        $image=(array)$image;
        $comma = ',';
        $json .=      $comma.'{"src":"'.$image['src'].'","order":"'.$image['order'].'"}';
    }
    $json .= ']';
```

Comment: NEVER manually craft a json string.  ALWAYS call `json_encode()` AFTER your array is fully populated.