# How i can merge more than two Json strings in php

Tags: php, json, merge

Below is my JSON strings like these, am trying to add jsons. How i can achieve.

```
$json1 = {"properties":{"title":"test","labels":["JanActual","Jan","Goal"],"values":["0","10000","0"]}}
$json2 = {"key":"Rental","type":"bar","values":["0","10000","0"]}
$json3 = {"key":"Service","type":"bar","values":["189","30000","0"]}
```

I am trying to use this to merge them and am expecting output like below

```
   {
    "properties":{
        "title":"test",
        "labels":[
            "JanActual",
            "Jan",
            "Goal"
        ],
        "values":[
            "0",
            "10000",
            "0"
        ]
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "key":"Rental",
            "type":"bar",
            "values":[
            "0",
            "10000",
            "0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key":"Service",
            "type":"bar",
            "values":[
                "189",
                "30000",
                "0"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174076/how-can-i-merge-two-json-strings-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decode json to php arrays, merge and encode back

```
$json1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$json1['data'] = array(
  json_decode($json2, true),
  json_decode($json3, true)
);

echo json_encode($json1);
```

Comment: Great answer, but I think you would also have to check for overwriting key->values when merging from two or more json sets.

Comment: @twg What does you mean? I can't imagine what can be overwriting because each json object put to separate element of an array with numeric indexes